# Need an efficient method for finding certain matrices

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to write a function which produces square matrices with certain characteristics. The function should have two inputs:

1. number of the rows, `n`
2. number of the times each element in the range 1, 2, 3, ..., n should be repeated in the matrix

So assuming the function is called `KOCH` then `KOCH[4, {2, 4, 5, 5}]` means the matrix should be 4 x 4 with 1, 2, 3 and 4 repeated respectively for 2, 4, 5, 5 times in the matrix, but each row in the output should be nondecreasing. And finally the function should find all the possible matrices, not only some of them.

The code I prepared is as following

```
Koch[n_, num_] := 
  Module[{list},
    list = Flatten@Table[Range[n], {i, n}];
    list = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Tuples[list, {n}]];
    list = Tuples[list, {n}];
    For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++, 
      list = list[[Flatten@Position[Map[Count[#, i, 2] &, list], num[[i]]]]]];
    list]
```

But as you notice what I am doing is to reproduce a large pool of the possible matrices and then filtering them with regards to the constraint on the number of repeatings. So it's inefficient.

My function works for up to `n = 4` even though it takes seconds for `n = 4` but for `n = 5` it fails because of memory constraint with shooting this error

> General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficientmemory available to complete the computation.

I need to compute for up to `n = 15` and, therefore, need a better algorithm to find all the possible matrices given the constraints.

Comment: Sounds like [the BKP problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is NP-complete. If so, I'd suggest giving up looking for ALL solutions, as there is no know algorithm which can solve it fast and completely.

Comment: Actually I need to have all the possible solutions!! The matrices are going to be ground of an economical theory evaluation!! What if I use a computer with 64GB ram and 12 CPUs???

Comment: Maybe `LinearProgramming` and `LinearSolve` would help.

Comment: May I ask you to explain a little more about your idea?? I am familiar with LP but no clues here!!

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, but I think it would be REALLY hard to enumerate ALL solutions for matrices as large as $n=15$. I don't have a proof, just intuition coming from the size of the solution sets for relatively small $n$s.

The example setting $n=4$, $c=\{2, 4, 5, 5\}$, where $c_k$ denotes the repeating times of $k$, has **6720** solutions.

A setting I tried with $n=5$, $c=\{1, 2, 10, 1, 11\}$ has **151510** solutions.

$n=6$, $c=\{8, 1, 11, 2, 8, 6\}$ has **?** (insufficient RAM here..) solutions.

Along with the number of solutions for $n=2$ and $n=3$, it looks like growing exponentially.

So I (wildly) guess the number of solutions for $n=15$ could require up to $\boldsymbol{10^{20}}$ **Bytes** or **one hundred thousand Peta Bytes** RAM, which will simply make it impossible even just to allocate them in RAM. Both time and memory costing are unpractical.

Comment: So what I should do is to change to another algorithm!!

Comment: @user8144 As the limit is the scale of the final solution set itself, I think any algorithm will not be able to improve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The approach here is to first make a list of required elements, then successively pick valid orws from the remaining list.

I have *not* verified this is absolutely correct , but it should get you started..

```
stillneeded[ needed_, rows_ ] := 
   Module[{n0 = needed}, (n0 = Drop[n0, First@Position[n0, #]]) & /@  Flatten[ rows ]; n0]
KOCH[n_, req_] := Module[ {}, 
     needed = Flatten@ Table[j, {j, Length[req]}, {req[[j]]}];
     possible = {#} & /@ 
           Union[Select[ Subsets[needed, {n}] , # == Sort[#] & ]];
    Do[possible = 
         Flatten[Table[(Join[possible[[j]], {#}] & /@ 
              Union[Select[ 
           Subsets[ stillneeded[needed, possible[[j]]], {n}] , # ==  Sort[#] & ] ]) ,
                         {j, Length[possible]}], 1] ; 
         Print["row", irow + 1, "npos", Length[possible]], {irow,  n - 1}] ;  
                possible   ] /; (Total@req == n^2)
     Length[ KOCH[4, {2, 4, 5, 5}] ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @george2079 ..... I added `DeleteDuplicates@(Sort /@ possible)` to your code and it works proper and fast for `n=5`, but for `n=6` it takes more than 6 hours to compute.... and imagine the larger `n`.... at least the RAM problem is vanished in your code!!!